# How to use telnet in Windows with the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, localhost, telnet

I've tried to run the command `telnet localhost 5554` in the command line, but I didn't succeed. It kept saying `telnet is recognized as an internal or external command...`.

The directory is set to where my Android SDK tools are installed (`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools`). Maybe this path is not correct but I don't know how to fix this. I have changed the path to other but no success.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're on Windows 7, telnet is not enabled by default. This [site](http://www.itdoescompute.com/2009/10/29/how-to-enable-telnet-in-windows-7/) has step-by-step instructions for turning it on. Once you do that, you should be able to telnet into the emulator.

Answer (score 4):

If you working in windows 7 telnet is not set by default. You must enable it from **Programs and Features** from Control Panel.

1- Turn Windows Feature on or off

2- check on Telnet Client / Telnet Server  // telnet client only is OK

3- OK // feature is on now

[image]

To test it's working from command line write *telnet*

To connect to your emulator just write this command

```
-->> telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
```

127.0.0.1 localhost

5554 port number in our case its 5554

[image]

You can run some commands in your emulator:

control power, network, simulate call, message ....etc

Example: `sms send 1254 this is message`

This command will send message to your emulator from this number *1254* 
with message *this is message*

### Update

easy way to get all devices connected IP with port to connect

just write in terminal this command

```
adb devices
```

Comment: How can I get port number from running android app on AVD (i.e. 5554 or 5556 etc)

Comment: you will find it on the top of your emulator look at last image (top left)

Answer (score 3):

You need to [turn on](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299942) the Telnet service. Alternatively, you can also use the Putty ssh client - http://www.putty.org/ to telnet to localhost 5554

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 Telnet Client and Server is be disabled by default. If you want to enable it, you can do so using the Command Prompt or via the Control Panel.

To do so:

```
Click on Start and under search type in CMD
Right click on CMD and click on Run as administrator
Enter the Administrator password if it prompt
Then type in pkgmgr /iu:”TelnetClient” to Enable the Client
And pkgmgr /iu:”TelnetServer” to Enable the Server
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Telnet client in your windows, install it, then you can connect.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The service Tlntsvr.exe, responsible for Telnet, was disabled at my machine. I Just put it to "manual start" and then started it.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the Telnet Client, it didn't work for me right on the Command Prompt. What I had to do:

1. Open the telnet prompt (Search programs, type "telnet.exe", or just "telnet" in C:\WINDOWS\system32).
2. On the telnet prompt, type "o localhost 5554".

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to the emulator with a shell, don't do it over TCP/IP. Do it with ADB:

adb -e shell

ADB resides in platform-tools.